# How do I set the function to automatically go to that code when I click the widget from flutter to the inspector?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

How do I set the function to automatically go to that code when I click the widget from flutter to the inspector?

develop environment is Android Studio.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and make sure to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Show us what you have tried so far (with code) and describe the specific problem that you are stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking, perhaps you want to hold down control or command, depending on your OS, and left click.
Usually that takes you to the code referring to that function or class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VSCode editor, you can do it with CTRL (command in macOS) + left click. When you hover your mouse to Widget's name, for example, it will highlight the text and then you can click it. It will bring you to the Widget class